# What are the miracles associated with Sri TirugnAna-sambandar?

Tags: shaiva-siddhanta, nayanar

He is one of the most famous nayanars of South India.

As he is well known for his devotion towards Lord Shiva.

What were the miracles in his life ?

Comment: I'm not certain shaivism can be replaced with shaiva siddhanta. One includes social aspects while the other is purely philosophical. Same with other branches of Hinduism like vaishnavism

Comment: @moonstar The poems of the Nayanars are a part of Shaiva Siddhanta. Tirumurai is  an important part of scriptures of Shaiva Siddhanta in Tamil.

Comment: Retain both if necessary. One does not subsume the other.